# Adding ImageView crashes android app widget

Tags: java, android, imageview, widget

I am making a very simple widget that shows an image using ImageView.

**My layout Looks like this**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dip">

    <!-- ImageView logo -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:src="@drawable/giants"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**My Widget Provider Class Looks like this**

```
 public class LogoWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager 
    appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

        // What Happens While App Goes Through Each Widget Id//
        for (int currentWidgetId: appWidgetIds) {

            // Define And Instantiate Variable RemoteViews widgetLogo//
            RemoteViews widgetLogo = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_logo);

            // Update Widget//
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(currentWidgetId, widgetLogo);
        }
    }
}
```

**The receiver in my manifest looks like this**

```
    <!-- Widget Provider Logo -->
    <receiver android:name=".LogoWidgetProvider">

        <!-- Tell The App That There Is A Widget To Display -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>

        <!-- Tell The App Where To Find Widget Data -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/appwidget_info_logo">
        </meta-data>

    </receiver>
```

**Lastly, the widget provider XML looks like this**

```
<!-- Basic Information For Widget Logo -->
<appwidget-provider
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_logo"
    android:minHeight="110dip"
    android:minWidth="110dip"
    android:minResizeWidth="40dip"
    android:resizeMode="vertical|horizontal"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="3600000"
    android:widgetCategory="home_screen">

</appwidget-provider>
```

For some reason, the widget crashes every time. If I was to switch ImageView To Button it works fine. What am I missing to make the widget display the Image?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post a stack trace also?

Comment: @MykhailoYuzheka There is nothing to show in the stack trace sadly. The app itself doesn't crash just the widget when I put in on my homescreen

Comment: You should phrase your question's title describing the problem. This way it's easier for more experienced developers to spot questions in their field of expertise. Also you should try asking shorter questions as they will get answers faster and the quality of the answer will be better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. You can use any image regardless of resolution but it needs to be put inside a box of 400 pixels by 400 pixels. I used paint pad to do it. Once it is in the box the image shows up